# How to unit-test with Mockito a method that tries and catches an Exception ("when exception caught")?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito

I've already tested a method that `throws Exception` which is easy to check in Mockito. Suppose I have a method called `sendEmail` that  `throws Exception`:

```
    Integer emailSmtpPortInvalid = 68;

    org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertThrows(jakarta.mail.MessagingException.class, 
              ()-> 
              {
                  emailServiceImpl.sendEmail(emailSmtpHost, emailSmtpPortInvalid, emailSmtpAddressFrom, emailSmtpAddressTo, "Test Subject", "Test Body");
              }
              );
```

But now I need to somehow provide test coverage for another method, `sendSuccessEmail`, which tries **and catches** any Exceptions. I need to do this to satisfy Jacoco's coverage requirements. What would be possible here? How do I **when an Exception** to re-throw it? I don't need to mock an Exception, I need to "when" it, e.g. when(Exception..).then(..) to be able to provide a unit test.

```
public void sendSuccessEmail(Ar11ResultBean ar11ResultBean, String emailSmtpHost, Integer emailSmtpPort, String emailAddressFrom, String emailAddressTo) {
    try {
        String emailBody = MessageFormat.format(Constants.EMAIL_BODY_SUCCESS, ar11ResultBean == null ? "" : ar11ResultBean.getRowsProcessed());
        sendEmail(emailSmtpHost, emailSmtpPort, emailAddressFrom, emailAddressTo, Constants.EMAIL_SUBJECT_SUCCESS, emailBody);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Log email error silently
        log.error("AR11 Application: Could not send success email due to error: ", e);
    }
}
```

I need something like **when exception caught**.

Comment: You mock the `sendEmail(...)`-method to throw an exception and `verify(...)` afterwards that it was called and that the correct result was returned from `sendSuccessEmail(...)`. Code coverage then will ensure that the catch block gets counted.

Comment: I did, but the caller methods are still flagged as untested in Jacoco. I have a line coveage requirements, code to unit tests: 0.91 vs 0.95

Comment: Please specify what "flagged as untested" means.

Comment: Coverage ratio, code to unit tests.

Comment: And did you verify that the method that was mocked to throw an exception was called?

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the log.error was correctly called.

You maybe need to mock your logger and then you can do something like this:

```
Mockito.verify(logger, Mockito.times(1)).error("AR11 Application: Could not send success email due to error:")
```

Comment: I can't access that logger from the unit test class.

Comment: If you cant access the logger than you cant do what you want to do. You need to find a way to access the logger.